# export table using expdp issue

Tags: oracle12c, expdp, oracle-dump

I am trying to export a table of size 2GB,   Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0/Non CDB)

[image]

I tried using the below commands,

```
1) expdp system/pwd tables=schema.tablename directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_xxxxx.dmp logfile=expdp_xxxxx.log

2) expdp schema/pwd@sid tables=table_name directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_xxxxx.dmp logfile=expdp_xxxxx.log 

3)  expdp system/xxxx schemas=xxxxxx include=table:\"'xxxxxx'\" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_xxxxx.dmp logfile=expdp_xxxxx.log
```

All the above commands work, but whent the export start, the estimated size shows as below...

**Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 195.2 GB**

whereas the table size is only 2 GB, i have checked the expdp.dmp size and it shows more than 12Gb before I killed the expdp job.

Seems like the entire schema export is being taken instead of just one table.

Please shed some light if I making any mistake in the export command or missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the CBO statistics prior to running the expdp
Also try add compression=all to the parameter file

Cheers
Brian